# Remove .php extension is not working

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I found a lot of tutorials and questions regarding to removing the .php extension in the URL. I have tried a lot of examples and until now it is still not working. This drives me crazy. I also want to put trailing slash at the end of the URL but first I would like to achieve this first. Currently I have tried this which is some of my solutions:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

and also this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Nothing is good. I am working in my laptop using windows 7, and using XAMPP. I simply created my .htaccess file and put it in localhost/myFolder. When I run in the browser, depending on my solution, (i) some times I got page not found, (ii) sometimes server internal error. Also when I run for example localhost/myFolder/index the URL will be redirected to localhost/index without myFolder. I wonder why is this happening and hope somebody can give me links or solutions because I tried so many of them. Thank you in advance.

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [L, QSA]
please try this

Comment: @KristerAndersson thank you,sorry I don't understand on the RewriteCond Backreference part, can you show the example? I am new to this.

Comment: @Asif I got server error with your example.

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

It work look like yoursite.com/test.php to yoursite.com/test

Comment: @Asif thank you but still same problem, it redirects me to localhost/index but not localhost/myFolder/index. Even I put "myFolder" manually, the page shows page not found.

Comment: RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1\.php

Please try this

Comment: @Asif appreciate it but again the same problem occured.

Comment: Ok but another temprary way u can create an other htaccess file in ur folder thanks

Comment: @Asif what the code looks like for another .htaccess? is it same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works fine for me:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /myFolder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thank you, but it is still not working. It redirects me to localhost/page instead of localhost/myFolder/page. Now I wonder where I should put the .htaccess file. I really don't know what is the problem.

Comment: Have you uncommented the `RewriteBase`? Put the .htaccess file in your `myFolder` directory.

Comment: Yes I have uncommented it and put in in myFolder directory. Strange it is not working.

Comment: Wow,work like charm! thank you so much, I guess it is the problem. I restart my laptop and run CCleaner, put your code and test it, working great! If you do not mind, how to add trailing slash and also catter GET variable in URL? Thank you.

Comment: Thank you, I am not in front of my laptop so I could not try it yet, will try it later and update you. I have some questions, why .htaccess can affect the cache? Also if my web server operates Windows / Linux, will this work in both environments?

Comment: I loss my formatting (CSS) when I put something like localhost/myFolder/support/. Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: got the formatting problem solved using `<base href="http://localhost/myFolder/" />` in <head> tag. Thank you so much for your help. Even you go for localhost/myFolder/support/ it is correctly displayed. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in /myFolder/.htaccess for hiding .php extensin:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/myFolder/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: thank you for your solution, it did not work for me. I can see the URL is good "localhost/myFolder/page" but the page is not found. I have used Krister Andersson solution. thank you again.

Comment: You have to use only 1 rule not multiple. Post your complete .htaccess in your question.

Answer (score 0):

A solution for your problem:

```
Options +MultiViews
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/myFolder/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

I just replaced your `-` sign in `multiviews` and it started working on my localhost